# Sampling from a Normal Distribution in SAS

Tags: sas

Suppose I know that the average age of males in a town is 50. The standard deviation is 10. How would I sample an age from this distribution using SAS?

Answer (score 1):

In a data step you can use `x = rand('NORMAL',50,10)`. SAS/IML has a different syntax. You may wish to set a random seed using `call streaminit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random data with that mean/std using the `rand` function:

```
%let numsampled=10;
data ages;
 call streaminit(7);  *initialize the seed;
 do id = 1 to &numsampled;
     age = rand('Normal',50,10);    
     output;
 end;
run;
proc print data=ages;
run;
```

If you want to do more complex sampling, such as generating a set and then sampling with replacement from it, you can first generate a population of N size above, and then use `proc surveyselect` to pull from that population.